# Unreachable code using switch statements in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

So I'm building an email administration app and although it is working with if statements, I am trying to incorporate switch statements. I am prompting the user using a scanner to select which department they are from while building their email associated with it. Although when I am trying to return this.department, it is saying it is unreachable. I feel like I am missing something very obvious.

```
// Ask for the department
private String setDepartment() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int department;
    
    System.out.println("Select your department:\n1. Sales\n2.Accounting\n3.Development\n4.N/A");
    department = sc.nextInt();
    
    while (true) {
        switch (department) {
            case 1:
                this.department = "Sales";
                break;
            case 2:
                this.department = "Accounting";
                break;
            case 3:
                this.department = "Development";
                break;
            case 4:
                this.department = "";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please choose a valid option (1-4)");
                break;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    return this.department; <-- Error: Unreachable code
}
```

Comment: You have an endless `while(true)` loop and you never break out of it.

Comment: Looks like your while loop is going to close your scanner and with it your System.in stream. You can't open that resource again once it has closed.

Comment: You never change department while in the loop.

Comment: So I changed the condition to while (this.department == null) and it seems to be working only for cases 1-4. If I enter a random value not 1-4, it prints out "Please choose a valid option (1-4)" infinitely even though I am putting a break statement underneath the sysout.

Comment: @DexterM. you need to spend a little more time just reading your code. Take a pen and paper out and just follow along, if that helps. Then you'll trivially find that the insides of your while loop __never change department__ - you do `department = sc.nextInt();` only before your while loop even starts. Computer just does what it is told, it doesn't try to intelligently figure out what you meant. It does what you say, not what you mean.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

problem is your **condition inside the while()** loop .**It set always to true** .**So code below the while loop never gets executed** .Try to have a different condition inside the while loop which terminates in a certain value.Otherwise you need place what ever you want to return inside the while loop.

**Extra: Please also place your `sc.close();` outside the while loop otherwise you can't use the resource after the first while loop iteration.so closing resource must be done always at the end.**

Solution 1:

```
while(updatedTerminationCondition){//change the termination condition





}
```

Solution 2:

```
while(true){




//place your return value inside here but then loop will only run once  
}
```

Comment: @DexterM. It should pal because when you enter a value which is not in the range of 1-4 then this.department wont get assigned by a value.So it's always null so your condition this.department == null is always true .That's why you are having an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `switch`-statement is in a `while(true)` loop that gets never exited. Unless you explicitly exit the loop e.g. by using `break` the program will never stop to execute the loop, meaning any code below it will never get reached, thats what the compiler is complaining about.